# Filter on dataset clears all bound controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filter

The following code works (rows are filtered by the select expression), but then all the controls in the datarepeater are empty.  When set to .DefaultView all records return and all controls have their values.

```
       Private Sub CheckBox_FilterApplied_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox_FilterApplied.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox_FilterApplied.Checked Then
        ' RichTextBox_Notes.DataBindings.Add("Text", dsTransactions.Tables("TransactionHeader"), "Note")
        DataRepeater_Transactions.DataSource = dsTransactions.Tables("TransactionHeader").Select("Applied = 0")

        DataRepeater_Transactions.Refresh()
    Else
        DataRepeater_Transactions.DataSource = dsTransactions.Tables("TransactionHeader").DefaultView

    End If
End Sub
```

Can't tell what is missing. Refresh is no help.

Comment: I think I need to focus on filter the dataset rows only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem because of the DataSource of the Textbox and Datasource of the DataRepeater.

I modified the code slightly, Please try it. Works for me.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Col1")
dt.Columns.Add("Col2")
dt.Columns.Add("Col3")


For index = 1 To 10
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr("Col1") = index.ToString()
    dr("Col2") = index.ToString()
    dr("Col3") = index.ToString()
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Next

Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dt, "Col1 >= 8", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", dv, "Col3"))
DataRepeater1.DataSource = dv
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The `DefaultView` property is typed as a `DataView` whose `IEnumerable` enumerates over a `DataRowView` array which enables you to use the standard binding syntax. However, the `Select` method returns an array of `DataRow` objects which cannot be bound in the same way. The simplest solution is to ensure you pass a `DataView` to the `DataSource` property.

```
If CheckBox_FilterApplied.Checked Then
    Dim dt As DataTable = dsTransactions.Tables("TransactionHeader")
    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dt, "Applied = 0", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    DataRepeater_Transactions.DataSource = dv

Else
    DataRepeater_Transactions.DataSource = dsTransactions.Tables("TransactionHeader")

End If
```

Also note, that can bind directly to the `DataTable` and do not need to explicitly use the `DefaultView` property as it will be used by default.

Comment: Shouldn't applying a dataset where a dataview is required cause an error?

Comment: @Jeff O - Where do you see me applying a DataSet? When `checked` is true, I'm using a `DataView`off a table in the set. When `checked` is false, I'm using a `DataTable` from the `DataSet`. IIRC, it is even possible to bind directly to a `DataSet`. Most controls will simply pull the first table on the set. However, that's not what I'm doing here.

Comment: Sorry about that (haven't looked at this for awhile), I meant in my code, but you are right it is not the dataset being applied.